# Django greedy characters missing in reverse urls

Tags: django, django-urls

I am trying to use the following rule to map urls in django

```
url(r'^(?P<permalink>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?$', views.page, name='page'),
```

This should match pages like

- site.com
- site.com/super-awesome-page/

This works however the reverse urls provided by the url template tag are missing the trailing / i.e. "site.com/page" these do get captured pattern but I want my links to show up in my page correctly how can I get this to work correctly.

I would have expected since the trailing slash is greedy it should be included in the reverse url.

Answer (score -1):

The trailing slash is optional in your regex, so django doesn't generate it for you for the reverse URL.

The easiest solution is probably to make the trailing slash non-optional. With the default settings, django will redirect the non-slash version to the slash-version. Easiest to just standardize on that.

Comment: Making it non optional causes ugly URLs for the example where Permalink matched nothing ( the root page). In addition although it is optional I would expect it to be included as ? Is greedy I would expect it to not be included in the reverse URL with the non-greedy ??